# Dúvidas de como "armazenar dados" e condições para esses dados serem printados

Tags: python

```
for i in range(n):
    #nome, peso, sexo(M/F), gravidez(S/N), Numero de doações, Dias desde a última doação
    nome, peso, sexo, gravidez, ndoacoes, ultimadoacao = input().split()
    print(nome, peso, sexo, gravidez, ndoacoes, ultimadoacao)
```

> Para seguir adiante com a doação, um doador deve ter no mínimo 50kg.
> Se mulher, não poderá estar grávida ou amamentando e, além disso,
> não poderá ter doado mais de 3 vezes nos últimos 12 meses e a última doação deve ter ocorrido,
> no mínimo, a mais de 90 dias. Se homem, não poderá ter doado mais de 4 vezes nos últimos 12 meses
> e a última doação deve ter ocorrido, no mínimo, a mais de 60 dias.

Eu não consigo pensar na forma de fazer esse programa, não consigo em como fazer as condições.
Como eu faço pra quando, por exemplo, for menor que 50kg  ele negar e dizer que não pode ser um doador?

**Vou dar um exemplo de entrada:**
3
50.0 M N 3 120
60.0 F N 2 60
61.5 F S 1 90
**E a saída:**
Número de doadores aptos do sexo M: 1
Número de doadores aptos do sexo F: 0
Peso médio de doadores aptos: 50.0

Comment: Já tentaste fazer um `if` testando o peso, e se for menor de 50, printar que não pode ser doador, por exemplo?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Já sim, mas a questão é que eu preciso pegar esses dados e "filtrar" eles, pra no final ter aquela saída que eu coloquei.

Comment: O negócio é que eu não consigo entender como eu faço pra "filtrar" todos eles com o IF, não consigo entender a lógica de como eu vou fazer isso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer a comparação de cada valor com cada critério e validar/invalidar conforme as regras.
No exemplo abaixo, a função `apto` recebe os valores de cada doação:

- peso
- sexo
- gravidez
- número de doações
- tempo desde a última doação

Cada valor é então comparado com o respectivo critério e se este não atende, é imediatamente marcado como **inapto**.

Quando todos os critérios são satisfeitos pelos dados recebidos, é feita a contabilização do somatório de peso, total de aptos, e total de aptos para cada sexo.
Ao final de tudo, é calculada a média de peso bem como apresentado os resumos.

```py
def apto(peso, sexo, gravidez, ndoacoes, ultima): 
    #O primeiro critério é o peso, pois é comum a ambos os sexos
    #se não atingiu o peso mínimo (50)
    if float(peso) < 50: 
        #já retorna como inapto
        return False
    #se é feminino
    if sexo == 'F':
        # não pode estar grávida
        if gravidez == 'S':
            return False
        #nem já ter 3 doações
        if int(ndoacoes) >= 3:
            return False
        #e a última tem que ser a mais de 90 dias
        if int(ultima) <= 90:
            return False;
        return True 
    #do contrário, é masculino
    else:
        # não pode ter mais de 4 doações
        if ndoacoes >= 4:
            return False 
        # nem ter menos de 60 dias da última
        if ultima <= 60:
            return False
    return True

peso_total = 0
total_aptos = 0
aptas = 0
aptos = 0
entrada = ['50.0 M N 3 120', '60.0 F N 2 60', '61.5 F N 1 90'] #input().split()
for doador in entrada:
    print(doador)
    peso, sexo, gravidez, ndoacoes, ultima = doador.split()
    esta_apto = apto(float(peso), sexo, gravidez, int(ndoacoes), int(ultima))
    if esta_apto:
        peso_total += float(peso)
        total_aptos += 1
        if sexo == 'M':
            aptos += 1
        else:
            aptas += 1

print(f'Número de doadoras (sexo feminino) aptas: {aptas}')
print(f'Número de doadores (sexo masculino) aptos: {aptos}')
if(total_aptos > 0):
    media_peso = peso_total / total_aptos
    print(f'Peso médio de doadores/as aptos/as {media_peso}')
else:
    print("Ninguém apto doar ")
```

Comment: Perfeito, só que o usuário que tem que decidir o quantos doadores quer colocar.

Comment: "n= input.()" e embaixo ficaria "for i in range (n):" e em seguida colocaria as informações, sexo, peso e etc. Tô tentando modificar o algoritmo aqui kkkkk

Comment: No caso, você precisaria de um `n = int(input)` para que o usuário escolha o número de entradas. O resto é praticamente igual.

Comment: Muito bom, consegui!! Obrigado <3